# "Perhaps" or "Maybe"?

Tags: word-choice, american-english, british-english, dialects

As a non-native speaker of English, I was once told in London by a learned British man that I should not use '*maybe*' for '*perhaps*' in the UK, as by doing so, I'd be following an American usage (so I'll be recognized as not speaking really 'British',  but mixing things up, which is never good, he insisted).

Is it indeed American to use ***maybe*** for ***perhaps***, or is just a matter of formal vs. informal (or less formal)?

Comment: In America, _perhaps_ is felt to be somewhat higher register, and perhaps faintly British, in intent at least. _Maybe_ is the ordinary word.

Comment: @John: In the UK, *maybe* can sometimes be perceived as a "lower register", but it's perfectly common in speech and I doubt many people normally make a distinction. Having said that, *perhaps* is far more common in both US and [US corpora in Google Books](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=perhaps%2Cmaybe&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=). I think OP's learned friend probably overstated the case, even allowing for the fact that he might also be somewhat behind the times.

Comment: Note that @JohnLawler did not say "... and *maybe* faintly British" :)

Comment: :) no ordinary word for no ordinary guy, right?

Comment: Perhaps has been around a bit longer, so maybe the foothold in the vernacular can be attributed to that.

Comment: To give someperspective on this, it is my personal experience that in the US only the most formal situatiion _perhaps_. It is in the same status as _shall_: it is recognizable in meaning to most people but would hardly if ever be used in day to day conversation.

Comment: @Mitch: That's about what I meant. Of course, I spent my career in the groves of academe, where speech register is just another weapon in the war of all against all. So I'm fairly familiar with it.

Answer (score 5):

Self-explanatory:

[AmE-2009, maybe, perhaps](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=maybe,perhaps&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=5&smoothing=0&share=)
[image]

[BrE-2009, maybe, perhaps](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=maybe,perhaps&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=6&smoothing=0&share=)
[image]

[English, maybe, perhaps](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=maybe,perhaps&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=0&share=)
[image]

[English Fiction-2009 maybe, perhaps](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=maybe,perhaps&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=4&smoothing=0&share=)
[image]

It appears that *perhaps* has always been more common, in AmE as well as BrE, though *maybe* seems to have become somewhat popular.

The trend in "English Fiction" shows that *maybe* is prevalent in informal writing (?because of use in speech) more than *perhaps*.

Even here, since 2005, *maybe* has been losing ground in written use.

I would believe the British are more "formal" even speech, whereas in the US, formal language appears only in serious writing.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One thing's for sure: one can't go wrong using perhaps every time...

Comment: Yes. *Perhaps* is the safer option. (Just not with the Am-teen crowd, though.) Do you see the nGrams? (I still don't.)

Comment: Yes, I do,  they tell the full story.